# Best way to store and keep track of private chat messages in Angular 2 applications

Tags: angular, socket.io, chat

I am trying to find the best way to store chat messages in the front end for the duration of the session. Given I am using socket io but also offline messaging when a message was sent to user A from user B when user A was offline. How I currently have the UI configured is I have a chat side bar that's visible when the user wants to chat with their friend they click the usersname ( think facebook ) what appears next is a bottom sheet that should contain the chat session(s) this bottom sheet is a separate component.

I thought about this from different angles and I think it's something that I should weigh in some opinions on. I have thought about performing just a GET request when the chat bottom sheet has been opened by the user ( could be really slow! ) and defeat the purpose of real time communication making the sockets useless. I have also thought about keeping all the chat objects in the LocalStorage and lastly, just keeping all the conversations in a global array that contains the chat objects.

```
 getMessages(socket) {
    let observable = new Observable(observer => {
      socket.on('incoming', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);
      });
      return () => {
        this.socket.disconnect();
      };
    })
    return observable;
  }
```

We can see there is an observable that's located in my service; in my component code I currently subscribed to this - this works fine; no issues - Question comes to, What next? given I have a chat bottom sheet and I want this message history to appear in the sheet for the user I clicked on

**ACTUAL:**
nothing is happening currently I am able to get the messages with success but as of current; I am just logging the messages out in the console

**EXPECTED:**
I click the username Bob on my sidebar my bottom sheet pops-up, I can now see my chat history with Bob for the day and can see new messages that may appear when i'm chatting with Bob.

Comment: socket.io is for the live chat component. It doesn't log stored chat history, that's on you to figure out on your own.

Comment: right, that's the point of my question though; how others have managed this in the past given the scenario(s) that are similar to mine.

Comment: You'd still need to store it somewhere (most likely a database or nosql) and do a get request for chat history, it wouldn't be so slow if you only grab say recent 20 messages, and request for next 20 if user scroll up the chat.

Comment: I am currently logging all the messages in the DB so there is a history; what do you think about keeping them in localstorage so i only have to worry about the new  message coming in and adding it to the array perhaps? not sure which is more expensive .. get request or finding and add then display the array of object on the template

Comment: opinion based or broad questions are innapropriate for SO.  Implementing a chat client has 100s of available tutorials and blog posts. SO is for specific coding problems

Comment: it's not really an open question but rather one about efficiency which can be objectively defined in this sense and has only so many option(s) - This question is also one about architecture which objectively makes or breaks code bases.

Comment: You did not really weigh the different solutions. If you use localStorage, the user might lose its chat history by clearing his browser cache. Which solution would be left appart from storing in a DB ?